# Unable to access "SharePoint Dashboard Designer"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, dashboard-designer-2013, dashboard

I am first time working on Business Intelligence Center site. And I need to use sharepoint dashboard designer. Getting an error, "Application cannot be started contact the application vendor". On clicking the dashboard designer in "Data Connection" webpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos, solution found just need to replace some of the sharepoint files, since an issue of an sharepoint update in october 2013, followed the steps as mentioned in below link,

http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_web_apps_server_2013_support_blog/archive/2013/11/19/performancepoint-2013-dashboard-designer-fails-to-start-after-october-2013-cu.aspx